# Diff'ing using the TFS API

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, tfs, diff

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the TFS Difference.DiffFiles() methods on files that are not under source control? I know when I am in the source control UI I can select local paths that let me move outside of the workspace.  I have made some efforts towards getting this to work but I am not sure how to read the DiffSegment results.

```
    options.Flags = DiffOptionFlags.None;
    options.OutputType = DiffOutputType.Unified;
    options.TargetEncoding = Console.OutputEncoding;
    options.SourceEncoding = Console.OutputEncoding;
    options.StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(memStream);
    options.StreamWriter.AutoFlush = true;

    DiffSegment seg = Difference.DiffFiles(pathA, Encoding.UTF8.WindowsCodePage, pathB, Encoding.UTF8.WindowsCodePage, options);
```

In some lite testing I can seem to see segments that get added but the OriginalStart seems to match the ModifiedStart so I just may not want to do this. If anyone has recommendations on a decent Diff API I'm open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tfs api most definitely allows you to compare two local files. I don't think you need most of the DiffOptionFlags, you can just do the following:

```
DiffSegment segment = Difference.DiffFiles(
    file1, 
    FileType.Detect(file1, null), 
    file2, 
    FileType.Detect(file2, null), 
    new DiffOptions());
```

As Mohamed describes briefly [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2009/03/08/how-to-diff-files-using-tfs-apis.aspx).

Russell describes in details what to do with DiffSegment [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/tfsversioncontrol/thread/7e473d46-888d-468b-b618-bb80655848f0).

For example I did the following

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(segment.Type + " " + segment.OriginalStart + " " + Segment.OriginalLength);
} while ((segment = segment.Next) != null);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This compiles, but it doesn't work for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16612156/284795

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer about using the TFS API is probably correct, but I thought I'd also mention that you can use the tool that Visual Studio launches if you don't want to mess with coding something using the API.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\diffmerge.exe`

In VS2012 and VS2013:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe`

Here is the usage:

```
Compare two files:
  diffmerge.exe Original Modified [OriginalLabel] [ModifiedLabel]
                [/ignoreeol] [/ignorespace] [/ignorecase] [/noprompt]
Merge three files into fourth file:
  diffmerge.exe /merge ServerInputFile LocalInputFile BaseInputFile ResultOutputFile
                [ServerInputFileLabel] [LocalInputFileLabel] [BaseInputFileLabel] [/noprompt]

Options:
  /merge - merge the files; without /merge, the files will be compared
  /ignoreeol - ignore end of line character differences
  /ignorespace - ignore differences consisting only of whitespace
  /ignorecase - ignore differences in casing
  /help - show this help message
  /noprompt - use Notepad for showing the diff or merge contents
```

So if you call diffmerge.exe without the /merge flag, the GUI will open. I'm not sure if that's the behavior you want or not, but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Looks like the executable was renamed to vsDiffMerge.exe in VS2012 and VS2013.