# How to use Team Foundation's library to calculate unified diff?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, diff

I want to calculate a [unified diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) comparing two documents. (The diff is to go in an email, and Wikipedia says unified diff is the best plain text diff format.)

Team Foundation has a [command line interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73(v=vs.100).aspx) do that

```
> tf diff /format:unified alice.txt bob.txt
- Alice started to her feet,
+ Bob started to her feet,
```

(Example files at https://gist.github.com/hickford/5656513)

Brilliant, but I'd rather use a library than start an external process, for the usual reasons.

Searching MSDN, I found Team Foundation has a .NET library [`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client(v=vs.80).aspx). However, the documentation didn't give any examples of calculating a diff.

How do I calculate a unified diff with the Team Foundation library?

---

Edit: I tried the method
 [`Difference.DiffItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.difference.aspx) but it didn't work—the file `diff.txt` was left empty.

```
var before = @"c:\alice.txt";
var after = @"c:\bob.txt";

var path = @"c:\diff.txt";
using (var w = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    var options = new DiffOptions();
    options.OutputType = DiffOutputType.Unified;
    options.StreamWriter = w;

    Difference.DiffFiles(
    before, FileType.Detect(before, null),
    after, FileType.Detect(after, null),
    options );
}

Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

Comment: Found someone else a few years ago with the same problem. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/828ad9b0-def5-461c-bf9e-180d57f167a8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it's not possible :( You can only do this from the command line with `tf.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try [DiffSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.common.diffsegment.aspx)

```
        var diff = Difference.DiffFiles(
        before, FileType.Detect(before, null),
        after, FileType.Detect(after, null),
        options);

        while (diff != null){                
            //DO What you like with the diff(s)
            diff = diff.Next;
        }
```

Comment: It's filled with indices that refer to the original file. You can retrieve the segment's contents from the file and print them. That should go into the do what you like bit.

Comment: Please could you give an example showing how to print a unified diff?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/7e473d46-888d-468b-b618-bb80655848f0